# Java - Iterator for initializing all classes with default name

Tags: java, class, iterator, initialization, startup

Is there a way to make a function to go through all classes in project and initialize them with name declared as static variable in the class or declared by some type of annotation.

I have something like this in mind:

```
int i = 0;
Class[] classes = getAllClasses();
while(classes[i] != null){
     String name = classes[i].getName();
     name classname = classes[i]();
     i++;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to obtain classes by names and create theirs instances:

```
public Object[] init(String... classNames) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
{
    Object[] instances = new Object[classNames.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++){
        // try to obtain class instance by name
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(classNames[i]);
        // this call require public no args constructor
        instances[i] = cls.newInstance();
    }
    return instances;
}
```